# regex output to a text file

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a python Script that write regex output (IP Addresses) to a text file. The script will rewrite the file each time it runs. Is there any better way to do it?

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')

with open('test.txt', 'r') as rf:

    content = rf.read()
    matches = pattern.findall(content)

    open('iters.txt', 'w').close()
    for match in matches:
        with open('iters.txt', 'a') as wf:
            wf.write(match + '\n')
```

Comment: Better way ? can you explain what you mean ?

Comment: Sorry, i mean if there is a shorter way to do it?
when i run the script on a big text files it takes long time.
I feel like it is not efficient enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote the code a bit.

1. I changed the regex to use `{3}` that way you don't have to repeat the same pattern so many times.
2. I added `os.path.exists` to check to see if the file already exists.  I think this is what you want, if not just remove that `if`. If the file already exists it **does not write**.
3. I combined the two `with`'s as you seem to be writing to a file and it doesn't make a ton of sense to keep on reopening the file to append a new line.
4. I renamed `pattern` to `ip_pattern` just for readability sake, you can change it back if you want.

Code:

```
import re, os

ip_pattern = re.compile(r'(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}')

if not os.path.exists("iters.txt"):
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as rf, open('iters.txt', 'a') as wf:
        content = rf.read()
        matches = ip_pattern.findall(content)
        for match in matches:
            wf.write(match + '\n')
```